# Marklogic - How to handle processing instruction in XML

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I need to get the attribute value from XML using X Query . But this attribute like Processing instruction . So how to handle this kind of part?

```
     Sample XML:
        <root id="12">
        <?test date="3/1966"?>
        <?Names name="Anto. 17"?>
        <title>AUDIT</title>
        </root>

Expected output:
    date = "3/1966"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it looks like a processing instruction then it is.

For a specific processing instruction specify the target.

```
data(//processing-instruction(test))
```

All processing instructions

```
data(//processing-instruction())
```